# If multiple IFs are null, do something

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am looking for suggestions for a solution and on best approaches to handle figuring out if multiple IFs are null.

I have:

```
if [ -n "$sfcompname" ]; then
        echo $sfcompname
fi
if [ -n "$sfcompip" ]; then
        echo $sfcompip
fi
if [ -n "$lacompname" ]; then
        echo $lacompname
fi
if [ -n "$lacompip" ]; then
        echo $lacompip
fi
```

.. I'm sure that can be done better, but my main problem at the moment is trying to then say:

if (all those IFs) = null

echo "Please check the name you entered and try again"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat silly, but should work

```
if ! [[ ${sfcompname}${sfcompip}${lacompname}${lacompip} ]]
then
  echo "Please check the name you entered and try again"
fi
```

Comment: Wonderful, silly indeed, but I'm just learning. It does work and I like it. Very straight forward. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use another variable for this which you initialise to a value and then change if any of the `if` statements fire. Then at the end, if it hasn't changed, then you know that *none* of them fired. Something like this will suffice:

```
fired=0

if [ -n "$sfcompname" ]; then
    echo $sfcompname
    fired=1
fi
if [ -n "$sfcompip" ]; then
    echo $sfcompip
    fired=1
fi
if [ -n "$lacompname" ]; then
    echo $lacompname
    fired=1
fi
if [ -n "$lacompip" ]; then
    echo $lacompip
    fired=1
fi

if [[ ${fired} -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'None were fired'
fi
```

Comment: Very sneaky, I like it :D Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the variable check short-cut:

```
name="$sfcompname$sfcompip$lacompname$lacompip"        
${name:?"Please check the name you entered and try again"}
```

This will exit the program if none of the variables are set.  The message is optional, it overrides the standard "parameter null or not set".